# How to stop the list at the last element?

Tags: java, android, list

I am trying to make something like a simple true/false game.

The problem is that I have lets say 3 elements(Or questions in my case) in my list. First question appears and you choose is it true or false, then a PopUp window appears with the answer, you press ok and a new question appears if your guess is correct. If not the app closes(for now). If you guess everything correctly, reach the last Question and answer it you are brought back to the first question. However if you answer it again you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3` error. So my question is. How can I make the app stop at the last question and when I answer the last question it would popup a window with a congradulations announcement, not the first question again.

Here is the **EDITED** code for the button True:

```
mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
               //Show the first answer on first button click.
                ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstas)).setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).answer);
        // When PopUp button closes open the next question with the if/else conditions.
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //if the question is true show next question/ else close app
                    if (type.get(count[0])) {

                        if(questions.size()-1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
                            //player has won
                            count[0] = 0;
                        else if(questions.size()-1 < count[0])
                            try {
                                throw new Exception("what?");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        else
                        count[0]++;

                        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                        pwindo.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            });

            }
        });
```

Here is the False button:

```
  mNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            initiatePopupWindow();

            ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstas)).setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).answer);

            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!type.get(count[0])) {

                        if(questions.size()-1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
                            //player has won
                            count[0] = 0;
                        else if(questions.size()-1 < count[0])
                            try {
                                throw new Exception("Invalid ");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        else
                        count[0]++;

                        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                        pwindo.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            });


        }
    });
}
```

Now the List goes on and on as I answer the same questions. I want the list to stop at the last question. For example when I answer the last questionin the list I get a popup window saying Congratulations!. or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
if (type.get(count[0])) {
    count[0]++;
    mQuestion.setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).question);
    pwindo.dismiss();
    //mPopupText.setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).answer);

} else {
    finish();
}
```

with

```
if (type.get(count[0])) {
    count[0]++;
    if(questions.size() == count[0]++) {
        //player has won
        count[0] = 0;
    }
    mQuestion.setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).question);
    pwindo.dismiss();
} else {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: won't this increment count[0] twice?

Comment: Hello. For some reason I am getting a strange error. I updated my question.

Comment: @MihaiC yea, but that is made in purpose, as the array size will be always +1 more than the count value, so to make the comparison the right way you must compare array-size to count+1

Answer (score 0):

The problem of **leaked window** you facing must be because you are dismissing the popup from an instance which is not holding the popup reference, so I think  you putting the onClick listener outside the activity or you are using it from a different intent, or may be you are closing the activity before dismissing the popup.

Comment: You need to close the popup before you finish your activity

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you just wrote here. By my understanding youre saying that the pwindo.dismiss should be somewhere else? But then why did it work correctly at first? Might it be a problem at the false button? Since my second question is false and the error occurs on that question. I edited my question with a false button code.

Comment: @NickF that what I'm said

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė and when you hitting true, the popup dismisses correctly ?!

Comment: And she didn't understands you

Comment: @NickF well, sry i understood that you saying that to me

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to not icrease count 2 times

If you start count[0] = 0, the first question will be shown, then in onClick  you are incrementing count[0] twice, so when you are comparing question.size() with count[0], you have 3==2 ? no, so when you setText it will show question 2 text, won't it?

My suggestion is :

```
if (type.get(count[0])) {

  if(questions.size()-1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
  {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("WInner")
            .setMessage("You won, play again?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // just close dialog
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

    // Create dialog from builder
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    // Show dialog
    alert.show();
    count[0]=0;
  }
  else if(questions.size()-1 < count[0])
    thow new Exception("Invalid ");
  else
    count[0]++;

  mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
pwindo.dismiss();
  } else {
   finish();
}
```

Try this, but I think the Leak exception is related to that you not are dismissing the window in some situation.

Comment: I think you've made a type-o somewhere since im getting else without if error, but I cant find where lol.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but If  its related to Exception, sorry I missed new, use throw new Exception("what you want to say"). Also I improved the parentheses

Comment: With your given code Im not getting the error finally. However the list never stops. It goes 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 and so on. I want thatt he List would end ant the last element 3. For example when I Answer the last question I get a popup saying Congratulations! or something like that. How can I do that? I edited my Question.

Comment: I updated it. Now when you won it will appear an alert dialog telling you that, and will ask if you want play again (dialog will close and count will be reset) or if you dont (activity will finish). I used alert dialog because i read that is not good that you call a popupwindow inside other